# Can I use user's quota when I request Google Speech to Text API

Tags: google-api, speech-to-text

I'm using google STT API. and that API has been limited with my GCP quota.

May I request with user's access token or something rely on user's quota, and extend my quota?

I know there are similar ways on using with Geocoding API. In my previous experiences, develop can charge the quota spending to the user, not the developer or project's one.

Does that works as same in Google STT API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the documentation found here [Quotas & limits](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/quotas)

You can request an increase to your quotas from the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). To learn more, see the information on [managing your quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota).

[image]

Quota increased need to be handled though your project they are not related to an access token.